# Derivative of matrix inverse using definition of Frechet derivative

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $F : Gl_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ is given by $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ Show that the Frechet derivative is given by $D_A F(h) = -a^{-1} h a^{-1}$.

Work done so far:

\begin{align*}
||F(u_0 + h) - f(u_0) + u_0^{-1}hu_0^{-1}|| &= || \Sigma_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(u_0^{-1}h)^ku_0^{-1} - u_0^{-1} + u_0^{-1}hu_0^{-1}|| \\
&= ||\Sigma_{k \geq 2} (-1)^k(u_0^{-1}h)^ku_0^{-1}||
\end{align*}

I am not sure the last element approaches zero as h goes to zero. If someone could explain that part.

Comment: Hint: (1) wlog let $u_0 = I$. (2) eventually $\|h\| < 1$. Therefore you can estimate the right side by $\sum_{k\ge 2} |h|^k$.

Comment: why can we assume that $u_0 = I$. I see the rest is just geometric series.

Comment: you can factor out $u_0$ from $u_0 + h$ and use the fact that matrix norm is sub-multiplicative

Comment: Can you show me the details as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3662806/568204)  for an outline. The point is that if you choose $h$ with small enough norm so that $\lVert u_0^{-1}\rVert\lVert h \rVert<1$, then you have an absolutely convergent (geometric) series, and using submultiplicativity of operator norm, you can bound that term as $C\cdot\lVert h\rVert^2$ for some finite constant $C$, namely $\lVert u_0^{-1}\rVert^3\sum_{k\geq 2}\lVert u_0^{-1}\rVert^{k-2}\cdot \lVert h\rVert^{k-2}$. Hence, the remainder goes to $0$ faster than $\lVert h\rVert$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: ^ my bad, I should have written $C(||h||)$... but this is no issue since $C(||h||)$ is a decreasing function of $\lVert h\rVert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We may assume $u_0 = I$ wlog, as multiplication is continuous and
   $$ (u_0 + h)^{-1} - u_0^{-1} + u_0^{-1} h u_0^{-1} = u_0^{-1}\left( (I + hu_0^{-1})^{-1} - I + hu_0^{-1} \right). $$
2. Using the Neumann series, we have
   $$ (I+h)^{-1} - I + h = \sum_{k\ge 2} (-h)^k = (-h)^2 \sum_{k\ge 0} (-h)^k = h^2 (I+h)^{-1} = o(\|h\|), $$
   as
   $$ \frac{\| h^2 (I+h)^{-1} \|}{\|h\|} \le \frac{\|h\|^2 \|(I+h)^{-1}\|}{\|h\|} = \|h\|\|(I+h)^{-1}\| \to 0 \cdot 1. $$

*Notes:*
If you already know that $F$ is differentiable, then you can simply apply the product rule as in @jlammy's answer. $F$ is in fact smooth, as it is a rational function by Cramer's rule.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the product rule -- derivative of $fg$ at $A$ is $H\mapsto f'(A)(H)\cdot g(A) + f(A)\cdot g'(A)(H)$ -- then you can apply it to the function $G=\mathrm{id}\cdot F$, i.e. $G(A)=AA^{-1}=I_n$ to get
\begin{align*}
0=G'(A)&=\mathrm{id}'(A)(H)\cdot F(A)+\mathrm{id}(A)\cdot F'(A)(H)\\
&= H\cdot F(A)+A\cdot F'(A)(H),
\end{align*}
which rearranges to $F'(A)(H)=-A^{-1}HA^{-1}$.