# The rank theorem (baby Rudin 9.32)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In baby Rudin, Rudin stated the rank theorem below:

**9.32 Theorem**

Suppose $m, n, r$ are nonnegative integers s.t. $m\geq r$, $n\geq r$.  Let $F$ be a $C^{1}$ mapping of an open set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, and $F'(x)$ has rank $r$ for every $x\in E$.

Fix $a\in E$, put $A = F'(a)$, Let $Y_{1} = \mathop{\mathrm{Im}}A$, let $Y_{2}$ be a complement space of $Y_{1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, and let $P$ be the projection $\mathbb{R}^{m} = Y_{1}\oplus Y_{2}\to Y_{1}$.

Then there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $a\in U$, $U\subseteq E$ and there is a 1-1 mapping $H$ of $V$ onto $U$(whose inverse is also of class $C^{1}$) such that

$$
F(H(x)) = Ax + \varphi(Ax)\ (x\in V)
$$
where $\varphi$ is a $C^{1}$ mapping of open set $A(V)\subseteq Y_{1}$ into $Y_{2}$.

**My Question** is:

It seems to be $A(V)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Therefore the definition of differentiation of $\varphi\colon A(V)\to Y_{2}$ seems to be nonsense, so is the definition of $C^{1}$-mapping. Is there any justification?

Comment: Rudin is claiming that $A(V)$ is open in $Y_1$ (as it should be, because $A$ is a surjective linear mapping of $\Bbb{R}^n$ onto $Y_1$, hence it sends open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ to open subsets of $Y_1$). Since $Y_1$ is a normed vector space (in fact a Banach space, since it is finite dimensional), the notion of differentiability makes perfect sense (you just have to modify definition 9.11 slightly [see this for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3662806/568204)). Alternatively, you can just use an isomorphism to map $Y_1$ onto $\Bbb{R}^r$ and look at the corresponding function there.

Comment: i.e choose an isomorphism $\theta:Y_1\to\Bbb{R}^r$ and then define $\phi:A(V)\to Y_2$ to be $C^1$ if and only if $\phi\circ \theta^{-1}: \theta(\phi(A))\to Y_2\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ in the "usual sense" (this definition is of course independent of $\theta$; and while this type of thinking is useful later on in differential geometry, I think the link above provides a clearer definition for now).

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.