# Trouble understanding the Gauss-Newton method to update a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian, total-variation

I want to find the P matrix that minimizes the function $f(P) = r(P)^Tr(P)$ with $r(P) = PX - x$ using the Gauss-Newton method.

with $X$ being a constant $m \times k$ matrix, $x$ being a constant $n \times k$ matrix, and $P$ being an $n \times m$ matrix.

I got the Jacobian matrix using the method described in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006567/how-jacobian-is-defined-for-the-function-of-a-matrix), $J = I_n \otimes X$.

Using the formula on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm), the Gauss-Newton equation should look like:

$$
P_{n+1} = P_n - (J^TJ)^{-1}J^Tr(P_n)
$$

using properties of the Kronecker product from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

$$
(J^TJ)^{-1} = ((I_n \otimes X)^T(I_n \otimes X))^{-1} = (I_n \otimes X^TX)^{-1} = I_n \otimes (X^TX)^{-1}
$$

and working it out on paper it seemed that:
$$
J^Tr(P_n) = (I_n \otimes X)^T r(P_n) = r(P_n) \otimes X^T
$$

Combining the two parts we get
$$
(I_n \otimes (X^TX)^{-1})(r(P_n) \otimes X^T) = r(P_n) \otimes (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$
$$

$r(P_n)$ is an $n\times k$ matrix and $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is an $ m \times k $ matrix so doing the kron product to them produces a $nm \times kk$ matrix.

Which is so close.

If it was $r(P_n)((X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T$ instead of $r(P_n) \otimes (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ it would produce a $n \times m $ matrix which I need for Gauss-Newton method equation from the top to work.

Can someone let me know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the objective function
$\phi(\mathbf{P})=
\mathbf{R}:\mathbf{R}$
where
$\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{x}$.

Taking a differential approach,
it holds
$d\phi=
2\mathbf{R}:(d\mathbf{P})\mathbf{X}$
from which we deduce the gradient
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{P}}
=
2\mathbf{R}\mathbf{X}^T
\rightarrow
\mathbf{g}
=
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{p}}
=
2 \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{R}\mathbf{X}^T)
=
2
\mathbf{J}^T
\mathbf{r}
$$

where
$\mathbf{p}=\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{P})$
and
$\mathbf{r}
=\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{R})$
where the following relation holds
$d\mathbf{r}
=
\mathbf{J}
d\mathbf{p}
$
with the Jacobian matrix
$$
\mathbf{J}
=[\mathbf{X}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}_n]
$$

The Hessian is found using
$d\mathbf{g}
=
2 \mathbf{J}^T
d\mathbf{r}
=
2 \mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{J} d\mathbf{p}
=
\mathbf{H}
d\mathbf{p}
$

The GN iteration writes
$$
\mathbf{p}_{n+1}
=
\mathbf{p}_{n}
-
\mathbf{H}^{-1}(\mathbf{p}_{n})
\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{p}_{n})
=
\mathbf{p}_{n}
-
(\mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{J})^{-1}
\mathbf{J}^T 
\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{p}_{n})
$$

Comment: Is `g` transposed in the final equation? Since `H` is an mn x mn matrix, and `p_n`, `g` are both mnx1 matrices, the update term in the final equation is: (mn x mn)(mn x 1) (mn x 1)(mn x 1) which doesn't work, but if I use `g^T` I get (mn x mn)(mn x 1) (1 x mn)(mn x 1) which gives me an (mn x 1) vector which is what I want.

Comment: I think `r` is evaluated at `p_n`. so `r(p_n)` is an nk x 1 matrix. and `g` is also evaluated at `p_n` so `g(p_n)` is an nm x 1 matrix. How do I evaluated `H^-1` at `p_n`?

Comment: I understand, `H^-1` doesn't rely on `p_n` so it doesn't do anything, `H^-1(p_n) = H^-1`.